# Retrieve all the values in a given range, i.e. XXXXX-XXXXX, JAVA

Tags: java, sql, database

I am having a problem with breaking down a range of data.

Basically, I have a table called Car models, and I want to allocate a range of stock for each car model.

So I have something like this...

```
CarID CarName NumberInStock Price
_________________________________
1      BMW     BMW00001-BMW00020  £35,000    
2      AUDI    AUD00001-AUD00100  £15,000     
3      TOYOTA  TOY00001-TOY00250  £9,000
```

I know how to retrieve the 'NumberInStock' from the database, however, I don't know how to break it down further, so that it is like BMW00001, BMW00002, BMW00003, ...BMW00020.

How would I code this?

Comment: This is not a forum but a Q&A site. I removed the redundant info from the question. Try focusing on the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, you might get one for that price if you help me out LOL :D

Comment: You want to get  BMW00001, BMW00002, BMW00003, ...BMW00020. from BMW00001-BMW00020  ? or a request in sql ?

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: @CladClad, ideally from a request in SQL. I would appreciate it if you could help me out

Comment: So for the BMW example you want 20 rows to be produced - one for each unique code is the range, or do you want 1 row with a value of `20`?

Comment: @Bohemian, yeah I want it to produce something like BMW00001, BMW00002, BMW00003, BMW00004, BMW00005, BMW00006, BMW00007, BMW00008, BMW00009, BMW00010, BMW00011, BMW00012, BMW00013, BMW00014, BMW00015, BMW00016, BMW00017, BMW00018, BMW00019, BMW00020

Comment: As one row or separate rows? Or don't care?

Comment: @juergend I think your edit was a little excessive. Namely, cutting out his statement that he is trying to learn Java and implement this db for "his family business" is highly relevant: It strongly implies that he can change the schema. If you are stuck with a schema designed by someone else, then the right answer to a question like this may involve writing complicated queries or sprocs or post-processing the query results in Java -- the approach most of the answers take. But if the poster invented the schema, the real answer is: Don't do this. Make a better schema.

Answer (score 3):

maybe I mistook the question but if you got the string : `BMW00001-BMW00020`

You can easily see and use a partern as you just need to split your string using "-" as your separater then you just have to suppress the 3 first char from each of your string. after that you got the beginning and the end of your for ;)

```
    String cars = "BMW00001-BMW00020";

    String []myCars = cars.split("-");
    String prefix = myCars[0].substring(0,3);
    int start = Integer.parseInt(myCars[0].substring(3));
    int end = Integer.parseInt(myCars[1].substring(3));

    java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("00000");
    for( int i = start; i < end+1; i++)
        System.out.println(prefix +  df.format(i));
```

this will gives you what you want ;)

Result :
BMW00001
BMW00002
BMW00003
BMW00004
BMW00005
BMW00006
BMW00007
BMW00008
BMW00009
BMW00010
BMW00011
BMW00012
BMW00013
BMW00014
BMW00015
BMW00016
BMW00017
BMW00018
BMW00019
BMW00020

But you shouldn't stock multiple line in one line trust me. Use two different column and you won't have anymore problems ;)

Comment: I want it to produce something like BMW00001, BMW00002, BMW00003, BMW00004, BMW00005, BMW00006, BMW00007, BMW00008, BMW00009, BMW00010, BMW00011, BMW00012, BMW00013, BMW00014, BMW00015, BMW00016, BMW00017, BMW00018, BMW00019, BMW00020
How do I do that, I extract it from the database and get "BMW0001-BMW00020'.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the String then try,

```
    String numStock="MW00001-BMW00020";

    String []numStocks=numStock.split("-"); 

    System.out.println(numStocks[0]+numStocks[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditto CladClad's answer. But let me add:

Small point: Note that his code does not include any error checking. I'm sure he left it out just to keep the example simple, but in real life, what if there's a record where instead of "BMW00001-BMW00020" it says "BMW1-20" or any of dozens of other variations. At the very least you want to give a clean error message on non-standard formats and not blow up with bad number conversions or index out of range.

As others have noted, this is a bad database design. If you control this, you should either:

(a) Change that "number in stock" column to 3 columns: car number prefix, starting number, and ending number. That would be much simpler to manipulate.

(b) But what happens if for some model the cars in stock are BAR00001, BAR00002, and BAR00004, but no 3? Is that possible or will you always have a continuous series? If there can be gaps, you really should have a separate table with the car numbers, with a foreign key pointing back to the model record. That is:

```
model (car_id, car_name, price)
unit (stock_number, car_id)
```